# How to display most recent node in different Panel

Tags: 7, panels

I have a magazine with two content types: Issue and Article. Regarding the Issue content type, I want one design for the most recent Issue and another design for all the past Issues. The past Issues are taken care of with Display Suite. For the current Issue I would like to use a panel/node variant. My question is, how do I display only the most recent node from the Issue content type without changing the design for all Issue nodes?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Views module to have custom content or links and show as a separate page or a block.

check this link:
http://drupal.org/project/views